# Set default value for radios in VBA

Tags: vba

I have a group of radios (OptionButton) in Excel VBA called `priority_y` and `priority_n` within the frame `fr_Priority`. How would I set priority_y as the default radio checked. I understand that it would have to be done under `Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()` but have no idea how to. I would appreciate any insight into the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set its value to 1 like this:

```
 priority_y.Value = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`priority_y.Value = True`

Credits to @AhmedAU

Source: [How to make a default Radio Button in Visual Basic Application (VBA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57438985/how-to-make-a-default-radio-button-in-visual-basic-application-vba?noredirect=1#comment101355524_57438985)

Comment: Who is AhmedAU? If you copied this from another SO post could you link to it here, please?